# How do I sum up the total value of each column for an individual key and then assign the total to a value in a different table?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to update a column in one table so that it sums-up all the values in another table associated with a particular key. I can't get the syntax right and I can't find an answer to this problem on the web.

I've tried changing where I put the "SUM" but it won't work.

Here's the code:

```
UPDATE purchase_order
SET total = SUM(SELECT total FROM purchase_order_items
WHERE purchase_order_items.purchase_order_order_no = purchase_order.order_no));
```

This should result in the "total" column from the purchase_order table being updated with the total sum of the "total" column from every entry in purchase_order_items where the order_no column key matches in both tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the SUM function in the subquery and assign the result to the main table..

```
UPDATE PURCHASE_ORDER
   SET TOTAL = (SELECT SUM(PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEMS.TOTAL)
                  FROM PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEMS
                 WHERE PURCHASE_ORDER_ITEMS.PURCHASE_ORDER_ORDER_NO =
                       PURCHASE_ORDER.ORDER_NO);
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `MERGE` statement:

```
MERGE INTO purchase_order dst
USING (
  SELECT purchase_order_order_no,
         SUM( total ) AS total
  FROM   purchase_order_items
  GROUP BY purchase_order_order_no
) src
ON ( dst.order_no = src.purchase_order_order_no )
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET total = src.total;
```